# Javascript String to Number type coercion

Tags: javascript, types

I ran into this issue the other day and couldn't figure out what exactly is happening under the hood. What are the rules for coercion of a String into a Number type? and why does it fail in the instance of '5.0.1'?

```
var numStr = '5.0';
var floatStr = '5.0.1';

//Passes
if (numStr >= 4) {
    alert('5 > 4');
}

//Fails
if (floatStr >= 4) {
    alert('5.0.1 > 4');
}

console.log(parseInt(numStr)); //5
console.log(parseInt(floatStr)); //5

console.log(Number(numStr)); //5
console.log(Number(floatStr)); //NaN
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent in mathematics? 5.0.1??

Comment: I realize 5.0.1 is not a number. I am looking for insight into the process of coercion in this case. What does parseInt do that the process of string -> num not do?

Comment: Might be worth noting here that if you use implicit coercion vis-a-vis `*1` you also get the same behavior as the explicit typecasting. That is `floatStr*1 // NaN`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, for one, `"5.0.1"` is not a valid `String` representation of a floating pointer number.  I would have expected `parseInt` to have failed as well.

**Edit:** However, as opposed to type casting the value, `parseInt` is a function that was designed to extract a value with more tolerance for noise.

The particular implementation details are defined in: [EMCA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

For instance, when applying a cast `Number([value])`, the `toNumber` function is used to perform the conversion -- described in section 9.3.1. The behavior of `parseInt` is described in section 15.1.2.2.

Comment: Thank you for answering in a serious manner. It's a simple question, but the detail was my interest.

Comment: No problem! I was curious about it too ;)

Answer (score 2):

5.0.1 is not a number. 5.01 is a number. It works with parseInt because parseInt is ignoring everything after the first decimal.

Answer (score 1):

`("5.0.1" > 4)` -> `(Number("5.0.1") > 4)` -> `(NaN > 4)` -> false.

Answer (score 0):

It will start ignoring when an invalid string appears, but will try to parse the first part.

```
parseInt("23.2332adsasd") -> 23
parseFloat("23.23adsdsd") -> 23.23
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Object.prototype.toNumber=function(){return this-0;}
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly and give some further information so your answer

Comment: The original question asks for an explanation of rules when strings are automatically coerced to numbers, not for a method of explicitly coercing an object to a number.